# The use of ContentNegotiationViewResolver in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

> As I know "ContentNegotationViewResolver" comes from the need
>   responding to client in various type of view.
>
> **The Scenario as I expected.**
>
> > For example,
> >     Supposing there is one resource "selectEmpList", I will call it.
> >     In some case, I want receive in XML format,
> >     in another case, I want to receive in form of jsp page.
> >
> > If I request call to server with "selectEmpList.do",  server will respond in jsp view
> >     If I request call to server with "selectEmpList.xml", server will respond in xml format view
>
> **Configuration as I did**
>   web.xml
>
> ```
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>         <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> dispatcher-servlet.xml
>
> ```
> <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
>     <property name="order" value="1"/>
>     <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
>         <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
>             <property name="mediaTypes">
>                 <value>
>                     xml=application/xml;charset=UTF-8
>                 </value>
>             </property>
>         </bean>
>      </property>
>      <property name="defaultViews">
>         <list>
>             <bean class="test.sys.view.NxaView"/>
>         </list>
>      </property>
> </bean>
> <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>      <property name="order"  value="2"/>
>      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jspview/"/>
>      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
> </bean>
> ```
>
> **Problem**
>   When I request call selectEmpList.xml   server returns jsp page in /WEB-INF/jspview/selectEmpList.jsp   and this page is not
>   exist, so result in 404 error.
>   Accurately What I want is "when I request to server selectEmpList.xml, Server respond in xml format data.
>
> Any answers will be appreciated. Thank you for you reading.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="order"  value="2"/>
     <property name="prefix" value="jspview/"/>
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

or

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>jspview/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: In advance, thank you for your reply. but What I want is "When I request call selectEmpList.xml, I receive data in xml format". Is this solution for this case? I'm not good at english. so maybe I mistaked writing question acuratlely. sorry

Comment: my code resolve your 404 error... with your code every *.xml and every *.do will be redirected to a servlet and the servlet will redirect to a jsp page.

Comment: I don't want every *.xml and every *.do are redirected to a jsp page. I want only every *.xml request are forwarded to "NxaView". and in NxaView I 'd like to implement rendering data. Is it possible?

Comment: I understood your problem but i don't know if it's possible or not. Maybe you can use spring controllers nad use @responsebody with the xml response. I don't have any other idea. sorry